# Assessing performance of a zero inflated negative binomial model

Tags: prediction

I am modelling the diffusion of movies through a contact network (based on telephone data) using a zero inflated negative binomial model (package: pscl)

```
m1 <- zeroinfl(LENGTH_OF_DIFF ~ ., data = trainData, type = "negbin")
```

(variables described below.)
The next step is to evaluate the performance of the model.

My attempt has been to do multiple out-of-sample predictions and calculate the MSE.

Using

```
predict(m1, newdata = testData)
```

I received a prediction for the mean length of a diffusion chain for each datapoint, and using

```
predict(m1, newdata = testData, type = "prob")
```

I received a matrix containing the probability of each datapoint being a certain length.

**Problem with the evaluation**: Since I have a 0 (and 1) inflated dataset, the model would be correct most of the time if it predicted 0 for all the values. The predictions I receive are good for chains of length zero (according to the MSE), but the deviation between the predicted and the true value for chains of length 1 or larger is substantial.

**My question is:**

- How can we assess how well our model predicts chains of non-zero length?
- Is this approach the correct way to make predictions from a zero inflated negative binomial model?

  - **If yes:** how do I interpret these results?
  - **If no:** what alternative can I use?

---

My variables are:

- Dependent variable:

  - length of the diffusion chain (count [0,36])
- Independent variables:

  - movie characteristics (both dummies and continuous variables).

    ---

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is straightforward to evaluate RMSPE (root mean square predictive error), but is probably best to transform your counts beforehand, to ensure that the really big counts do not dominate this sum.

You may find false negative and false positive error rates (FNR and FPR) to be useful here. FNR is the chance that a chain of actual non-zero length is predicted to have zero length (i.e. absence, also known as negative). FPR is the chance that a chain of actual zero length is falsely predicted to have non-zero (i.e. positive) length. I suggest doing a Google on these terms to find a paper in your favourite quantitative journals or a chapter in a book that helps explain these simply. For ecologists I tend to go back to Fielding & Bell (1997, Environmental Conservation).
First, let's define a repeatable example, that anyone can use (not sure where your trainData comes from). This is from help on zeroinfl function in the pscl library:

```
    # an example from help on zeroinfl function in pscl library
    library(pscl)
    fm_zinb2 <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | ., data = bioChemists, dist = "negbin")
```

There are several packages in R that calculate these. But here's the by hand approach. First calculate observed and predicted values.

```
    # store observed values, and determine how many are nonzero
    obs <- bioChemists$art
    obs.nonzero <- obs > 0
    table(obs)
    table(obs.nonzero)

    # calculate predicted counts, and check their distribution
    preds.count <- predict(fm_zinb2, type="response")
    plot(density(preds.count))

    # also the predicted probability that each item is nonzero
    preds <- 1-predict(fm_zinb2, type = "prob")[,1]
    preds.nonzero <- preds > 0.5
    plot(density(preds))
    table(preds.nonzero)
```

Then get the confusion matrix (basis of FNR, FPR)

```
    # the confusion matrix is obtained by tabulating the dichotomized observations and predictions
    confusion.matrix <- table(preds.nonzero, obs.nonzero)
    FNR <- confusion.matrix[2,1] / sum(confusion.matrix[,1])
    FNR
```

In terms of calibration we can do it visually or via calibration

```
    # let's look at how well the counts are being predicted
    library(ggplot2)
    output <- as.data.frame(list(preds.count=preds.count, obs=obs))
    ggplot(aes(x=obs, y=preds.count), data=output) + geom_point(alpha=0.3) + geom_smooth(col="aqua")
```

Transforming the counts to "see" what is going on:

```
    output$log.obs <- log(output$obs)
    output$log.preds.count <- log(output$preds.count)
    ggplot(aes(x=log.obs, y=log.preds.count), data=output[!is.na(output$log.obs) & !is.na(output$log.preds.count),]) + geom_jitter(alpha=0.3, width=.15, size=2) + geom_smooth(col="blue") + labs(x="Observed count (non-zero, natural logarithm)", y="Predicted count (non-zero, natural logarithm)")
```

In your case you could also evaluate the correlations, between the predicted counts and the actual counts, either including or excluding the zeros.

So you could fit a regression as a kind of calibration to evaluate this!
However, since the predictions are not necessarily counts, we can't use a poisson
regression, so instead we can use a lognormal, by regressing the log 
prediction against the log observed, assuming a Normal response.

```
    calibrate <- lm(log(preds.count) ~ log(obs), data=output[output$obs!=0 & output$preds.count!=0,])
    summary(calibrate)
    sigma <- summary(calibrate)$sigma
    sigma
```

There are more fancy ways of assessing calibration I suppose, as in any modelling exercise ... but this is a start.

For a more advanced assessment of zero-inflated models, check out the ways in which the log likelihood can be used, in the references provided for the zeroinfl function. This requires a bit of finesse.